# Save scraped text into different txt files

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping some info from different URL's and want to save each info into a .txt. First I've got the list of URL's I needed:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.imagino.com.br/gerador/listagem_senadores.php", headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
sep = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = [link.get('href') for link in sep.select('a')]
```

Then from this URL list I want to extract the info from class = "resumo" and save each in a separated txt file that has the name contained in the class = "nome":

```
for url in links:
    pg = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pg.content, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find('div', class_ = 'nome').text
    res = soup.find('div', class_ = 'resumo').text
    with open("%s.txt" % \ (name), "a+") as f:
        for i in range(0, len(res)):
            print(res)
            f.write(res)
```

This returns this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-151-3aeb1e867f0f>", line 6
    with open("%s.txt" % \ (name), "a+") as f:
                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I have searched a lot and couldn't find an answer. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: There is a backslash \ in the line which shouldn't be there.

Comment: What a basic mistake! Thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

`with open("%s.txt" % \ (name), "a+") as f:`

remove "\" after the "%"
"\" specifies a line break, basically it splits a single line of code into two lines for the sake of readability.

Comment: Didn't realized that it was the "\". Thanks. However, now that I'm running the code, it is saving hundreds of times the same text. Might you know what I can do?

Comment: just remove the loop, and it should fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks @ruhaib it did work now.